# How to get the previous value in sql server Trigger AFTER Update Statement

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know how can I retrieve the older value after updated. I am using this in After update trigger and the database being used is MSSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get data from DELETED table

```
SELECT ColumnName from DELETED
```

Comment: "Use the inserted and deleted Tables": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a trigger, you can get the pre-update value from the `deleted` virtual table.